# Server opens /search.php instead of /search/

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, i have a simple .htaccess for my engine. It simply rewrites all requests to index.php (much like Wordpress does).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Now, i've run into an issue. I have search.php, which should be included with index.php. But, when i try to open example.com/search/ (which should be rewrited to index.php), it actually opens search.php which is in the same directory. How can i tell the engine to disable this strange 'alias'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is probably caused by the [*MultiViews* option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews). Try to disable it with:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Thanks! This really solved an issue, i'm not good in htaccess so i didn't even how to search for it :)

Comment: +1: I ran into the same issue last night and just randomly saw this thread, followed the link, and learned something. thanks :)